# I want to use a dot in a while loop

Tags: loops, variables

```
while ((insert)!=(".")):
round=round+1
insert=input("Your ",round,". word please: \n")
```

I want that the loop runs as long as the variable "insert" is not a dot.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use the text prompt incorrectly. Try this code.

```
round =1
insert=input(f"Your {round}. word please: \n")
while ((insert)!=(".")):
    round=round+1
    insert=input(f"Your {round}. word please: \n")
```